# How to run ogrinfo for files listed in a CSV?

Tags: ogr, ogrinfo

I am using this code to extract info's of all the tab files in a folder. We have a `csv` list which has, say 100 file names out of 500 files in that folder. How to modify the code only to do ogrinfo's on those particular 100 files listed in a `csv` ?

```
for /R .\ %%f IN ("*.tab") DO ogrinfo -al -so "%%f" >>U:\QAQC_131.csv
```

Edit: This code works fine for me, even the file path has spaces in it

```
for /F "delims=" %%i IN (D:\QAQC\Open_multi.csv) DO ogrinfo -al -so "%%i" >>U:\QAQC_131.txt
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206114/batch-files-how-to-read-a-file

Comment: I tried with this one as mentioned in the link provided. FOR /F %%i IN (D:\QAQC\QAQC_131.csv) DO @echo %%i. But, it's not working

And, I don't know how come this is off-topic. ogrinfo in pretty much related to open source GIS and i don't see any reason to ask the questions in software development

Comment: the fact you are running ogrinfo is irrelevant to the question so it is off topic. As you say using echo will work as well.

Comment: works for me C:\Users\ian\Downloads>FOR /F %i IN (test.txt) do @echo %i gives 
file1
file2
file3

Comment: I am using this code for /F %%i IN (D:\RTXQAQC\Open_multi.csv) DO ogrinfo -al -so "%%i" >>U:\RTXQAQC_131.txt. It's generating the output txt file. But not reading the path since the path in Open_multi.csv has spaces. Will be of great help if you could tell how to make this code to read paths with spaces